# Why the different jail terms for the brigatisti involved in Aldo Moro's death?

Tags: italy, terrorism, 1970s

Wikipedia's [summary of the sentences](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caso_Moro#Cattura_e_condanne_dei_brigatisti_partecipanti_all.27agguato_di_via_Fani_e.2Fo_al_sequestro_Moro) applied to each of the *brigatisti* involved in Aldo Moro's death shows a wide range of jail terms.

In particular Barbara Balzerani served 21 years until 2011 while Mario Moretti who is thought to have actually carried out Moro's execution only served 15. Why the differences?

Comment: Perhaps issues with evidence or maybe some turned state's witnesses or whatever.

Comment: Moretti was sentenced to six life sentences, Barbara Balzerani to one. So, the actual sentences seem to be more inline with their participation, although both were paroled. Also, it was never proven in court that Moretti carried out the execution.

Comment: @YannisRizos - answer?